# Multiple Drop down Not Working in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hi Friends Good Morning
I have Created an Page like Shopping Cart in that i am using many Drop down field [example 8 drop downs in a single page].Using drop down i can add as much as quantity i needed and amount should be increased on the basis of Quantity changes using PHP 
 i have the following Problems while running it.
 
1.When i click one drop down the value changes to 0 automatically.
**Second Problem has been Solved** 
**2.SOLVED**
2.While Clicking the Second Drop down box the page get refreshed and First value has been cleared.

Here is the Coding

```
<form action="" method="get" name="months">
<select id="selectId" onchange="this.form.submit()" name="month" >
 <option   value="0">0</option>
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option  value="2">2</option>
 <option  value="3">3</option>
 <option  value="4">4</option>
 <option  value="5">5</option>
 <option  value="6">6</option>
 <option  value="7">7</option>
 <option  value="8">8</option>
 <option  value="9">9</option>
 <option  value="10">10</option>
 <option  value="11">11</option>
 <option  value="12">12</option>
 </select><br><br></form>
 <?php
$rs='5000';
$mul=$_REQUEST['month'];
$multiply= $rs*$mul;
?></td><td><?php echo "Rs.$multiply"; ?></td></tr> 

<form action="" method="get" name="months">
<select id="selectId" onchange="this.form.submit()" name="month1" >
 <option   value="0">0</option>
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option  value="2">2</option>
 <option  value="3">3</option>
 <option  value="4">4</option>
 <option  value="5">5</option>
 <option  value="6">6</option>
 <option  value="7">7</option>
 <option  value="8">8</option>
 <option  value="9">9</option>
 <option  value="10">10</option>
 <option  value="11">11</option>
 <option  value="12">12</option>
 </select><br><br></form>
 <?php
$rs='1000';
$mul=$_REQUEST['month1'];
$multiply= $rs*$mul;
?></td><td><?php echo "Rs.$multiply"; ?></td></tr>
```

For More Information here is the Screen Shot -->[image: CLICK HERE]<--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>SO - Cart</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="get" name="months">
<select id="selectId" onchange="this.form.submit()" name="month" >
 <?php
for($i=0;$i<=12;$i++){
    if($i==$_REQUEST['month']) {
        echo '<option selected="selected"   value='.$i.'>'.$i.'</option>';
    }
    else{
        echo '<option   value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
    }
}
?>
</select><br><br>
</form>
<?php
    $mul = 0;
    $rs='5000';
    $mul=$_GET['month'];
    $multiply= $rs*$mul;
?>
<?php echo "Rs ".$multiply; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Only '$i' is displaying as an output.. values are not displaying. @duikboot

Comment: Oh, I made probably a mistake with the '"quotes"'. 
Can you test again now? Thanks! ( Here it's working).
http://i44.tinypic.com/dbnkvo.png

Comment: No again only Drop down box is appearing with `'$i'` value @duikboot

Comment: Please save your pages as dropdown.php.

Comment: Oops just made a mistake i tried this one.. works fine with one drop down box but when i put 2 - 3 drop box its does not work only one value is working another one gets refresh. @Duikboot

Comment: I have just made some modification in your code and it works fine. the Modified Code is Below one. @Duikboot

Answer (score 1):

*onchange="this.form.submit()"*  is causing the page to submit and refresh every time you change the selected item.

This means, you either use a session to remember the values, or you can remove *"onchange="this.form.submit()"* and put a submit button inside the form:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

If you are trying not to refresh the page, you need to use ajax to call a web-service that will return JSON.

Comment: Your Code Solves the Second Problem but The first Dropdown Box values changes to 0 automatically. @Mark

Comment: only drop down work while i run it with a php code its not working.. @mark

Answer (score 0):

1) you are missing an if statement in your `<option>` to set `selected="selected"` for each of your lines do the following:

```
<option value="1" <?php if($_REQUEST['month'] == 1){echo 'selected="selected"';}?>>1</option>
```

probably best to do it in a loop.

2) I don't see a "second drop down box" however, in the example above - you have an event handler that submits the form (aka refreshes the page) after it is changed.

Comment: For Example i just posted the first Drop down but you can see the real scenario in the picture @Zack

Comment: @coolprarun, just updated my answer, you are using $_GET instead of $_POST, however I used $_REQUEST to match your code. If you use the above code in a loop it will check for each "month" option to see if it is the selected one, if it is it flags it as `selected`

Answer (score 0):

In stead of option of select use php code to create option, it will also reduce code in the page.

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<=12;$i++){
    if($i==$_REQUEST['month']) {
        echo '<option selected="selected"   value="'.$i.'">"'.$i.'"</option>';
    }
    else{
        echo '<option   value="'.$i.'">"'.$i.'"</option>';
    }
}
?>
```

For each select box use can use above code. but need to update request parameter `$_REQUEST['month']` in `if` condition.

Answer (score 0):

Working Code Modified From above **Duikboot's** Code.

Just Inserted my PHP code above the Form.It works Fine with it.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>SO - Cart</title>
</head>
<body><?php
$mul = 0;
$rs='5000';
$mul=$_GET['month'];
$multiply1= $rs*$mul;
?>

<?php
$mul = 0;
$rs='2000';
$mul=$_GET['months'];
$multiply= $rs*$mul;
?>

<form action="" method="get" name="months">
<select id="selectId" onchange="this.form.submit()" name="month" >
 <?php
for($i=0;$i<=12;$i++){
if($i==$_REQUEST['month']) {
    echo '<option selected="selected"   value='.$i.'>'.$i.'</option>';
}
else{
    echo '<option   value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
}
}
?>
</select>
<?php echo "Rs ".$multiply1; ?><br><br>
<select id="selectId" onchange="this.form.submit()"  name="months" >
 <?php
for($i=0;$i<=12;$i++){
if($i==$_REQUEST['months']) {
    echo '<option selected="selected"   value='.$i.'>'.$i.'</option>';
}
else{
    echo '<option   value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
}
}
?>
</select>
<?php echo "Rs ".$multiply; ?>
<input type="submit" />
</form><br><br>
</body>
</html>
```